# how to select and extract texts between two elements?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to scrape [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) website using scrapy. The page structure looks like this:

```
<div class="list">
  <a id="follows" name="follows"></a>
 <h4 class="li_group">Follows</h4>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="...">Star Trek</a></div> 
 <div class="soda even"><a href="...</a></div>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek: The Motion Picture</a></div>
 <div class="soda even"><a href="..">Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan</a></div>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek III: The Search for Spock</a></div>
 <div class="soda even"><a href="..">Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home</a></div>
  <a id="followed_by" name="followed_by"></a>
 <h4 class="li_group">Followed by</h4>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek V: The Final Frontier</a></div>
 <div class="soda even"><a href="..">Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country</a></div>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek: Deep Space Nine</a></div>
 <div class="soda even"><a href="..">Star Trek: Generations</a></div>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek: Voyager</a></div>
 <div class="soda even"><a href="..">First Contact</a></div>
   <a id="spin_off" name="spin_off"></a>
 <h4 class="li_group">Spin-off</h4>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Transinium Challenge</a></div>
 <div class="soda even"><a href="..">A Night with Troi</a></div>
 <div class="soda odd"><a href="..">Star Trek: Deep Space Nine</a></div
</div>
```

I want to select and extract the texts between: `<h4 class="li_group">Follows</h4>` and `<h4 class="li_group">Followed by</h4>`then texts between `<h4 class="li_group">Followed by</h4>` and `<h4 class="li_group">Spin-off</h4>`
I tried this code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.css("div.list"):
        item = ImdbcoItem()
        item['Follows'] = sel.css("a#follows+h4.li_group ~ div a::text").extract(),
        item['Followed_by'] = sel.css("a#vfollowed_by+h4.li_group ~ div a::text").extract(),
        item['Spin_off'] = sel.css("a#spin_off+h4.li_group ~ div a::text").extract(),
    return item
```

But this the first item extracts all divs not just divs between `<h4 class="li_group">Follows</h4>` and `<h4 class="li_group">Followed by</h4>`
**Any Help Would Be Really Helpful!!**

Comment: just in cases it helps, imdb.com has an (un)?official API where you can get all this data clean, if i remember well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extraction pattern I like to use for these cases is:

- loop over the "boundaries" (here, `h4` elements)
- while enumerating them starting from 1
- using XPath's `following-sibling` axis, like in @Andersson's answer, to get elements before the next boundary,
- and filtering them by counting the number of preceding "boundary" elements, since we know from our enumeration where we are

This would be the loop:

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn'
(...)
>>> for cnt, h4 in enumerate(response.css('div.list > h4.li_group'), start=1):
...     print(cnt, h4.xpath('normalize-space()').get())
... 
1 Follows 
2 Followed by 
3 Edited into 
4 Spun-off from 
5 Spin-off 
6 Referenced in 
7 Featured in 
8 Spoofed in
```

And this is one example of using the enumeration to get elements between boundaries (note that this use XPath variables with `$cnt` in the expression and passing `cnt=cnt` in `.xpath()`):

```
>>> for cnt, h4 in enumerate(response.css('div.list > h4.li_group'), start=1):
...     print(cnt, h4.xpath('normalize-space()').get())
...     print(h4.xpath('following-sibling::div[count(preceding-sibling::h4)=$cnt]',
                       cnt=cnt).xpath(
                          'string(.//a)').getall())
... 
1 Follows 
['Star Trek', 'Star Trek: The Animated Series', 'Star Trek: The Motion Picture', 'Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan', 'Star Trek III: The Search for Spock', 'Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home']
2 Followed by 
['Star Trek V: The Final Frontier', 'Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country', 'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine', 'Star Trek: Generations', 'Star Trek: Voyager', 'First Contact', 'Star Trek: Insurrection', 'Star Trek: Enterprise', 'Star Trek: Nemesis', 'Star Trek', 'Star Trek Into Darkness', 'Star Trek Beyond', 'Star Trek: Discovery', 'Untitled Star Trek Sequel']
3 Edited into 
['Reading Rainbow: The Bionic Bunny Show', 'The Unauthorized Hagiography of Vincent Price']
4 Spun-off from 
['Star Trek']
5 Spin-off 
['Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Transinium Challenge', 'A Night with Troi', 'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine', "Star Trek: The Next Generation - Future's Past", 'Star Trek: The Next Generation - A Final Unity', 'Star Trek: The Next Generation: Interactive VCR Board Game - A Klingon Challenge', 'Star Trek: Borg', 'Star Trek: Klingon', 'Star Trek: The Experience - The Klingon Encounter']
6 Referenced in 
(...)
```

Here's how you could use that to populate and item (here, I'm using a simple dict just for illustration):

```
>>> item = {}
>>> for cnt, h4 in enumerate(response.css('div.list > h4.li_group'), start=1):
...     key = h4.xpath('normalize-space()').get().strip() # there are some non-breaking spaces
...     if key in ['Follows', 'Followed by', 'Spin-off']:
...         values = h4.xpath('following-sibling::div[count(preceding-sibling::h4)=$cnt]',
...                        cnt=cnt).xpath(
...                           'string(.//a)').getall()
...         item[key] = values
... 

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(item)
{'Followed by': ['Star Trek V: The Final Frontier',
                 'Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country',
                 'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine',
                 'Star Trek: Generations',
                 'Star Trek: Voyager',
                 'First Contact',
                 'Star Trek: Insurrection',
                 'Star Trek: Enterprise',
                 'Star Trek: Nemesis',
                 'Star Trek',
                 'Star Trek Into Darkness',
                 'Star Trek Beyond',
                 'Star Trek: Discovery',
                 'Untitled Star Trek Sequel'],
 'Follows': ['Star Trek',
             'Star Trek: The Animated Series',
             'Star Trek: The Motion Picture',
             'Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan',
             'Star Trek III: The Search for Spock',
             'Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home'],
 'Spin-off': ['Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Transinium Challenge',
              'A Night with Troi',
              'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine',
              "Star Trek: The Next Generation - Future's Past",
              'Star Trek: The Next Generation - A Final Unity',
              'Star Trek: The Next Generation: Interactive VCR Board Game - A '
              'Klingon Challenge',
              'Star Trek: Borg',
              'Star Trek: Klingon',
              'Star Trek: The Experience - The Klingon Encounter']}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. but I couldn't figure out how to use this in my code. can you please give a hint or provide to me a code to use?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use below XPath expressions to fetch

- all text nodes for "Follows" block:

  ```
  //div[./preceding-sibling::h4[1]="Follows"]//text()
  ```
- all text nodes for "Followed by" block:

  ```
  //div[./preceding-sibling::h4[1]="Followed by"]//text()
  ```
- all text nodes for "Spin off" block:

  ```
  //div[./preceding-sibling::h4[1]="Spin-off"]//text()
  ```

Comment: You could even simplify `[./preceding-sibling::h4[1][.="Follows"]]` into `[./preceding-sibling::h4[1]="Follows"]`

Comment: You are just awesome sir Andersson. What an expression!!! Is it possible to create css selector with the same elements to locate the same thing? One example would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to transform provided XPath expressions into identical CSS selectors. I know that there is `!` and `?` symbols for instant previous and preceding elements, but it seem that they not yet supported...

Comment: For the sake of learning, one last thing to know sir Andersson on this topic. Why "h4[1]", I meant why not index [0] or [2] in the xpath you created above? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: `h[1]` means the first preceding header. Note that unlike in programming languages where indexation starts with `0`, in XPath indexation starts with `1`