# How can i export scraped data to csv file in the right format?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I made an improvement to my code according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958106/8476752) suggestion from @paultrmbrth. what i need is to scrape data from pages that are similar to [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) and [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094118/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) one and i want the csv output to be like the picture below.[image]

But my code's csv output is little messy, like this:
[image]

I have two questions, Is there anyway that the csv output can be like the first picture? and my second question is, i want the movie tittle to be scrapped too, Please give me a hint or provide to me a code that i can use to scrape the movie title and the contents.

**UPDATE**
The problem has been solved by Tarun Lalwani perfectly. But Now, the csv File's Header only contains the first scraped url categories. for example when i try to scrape [this webpage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093777/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) which has `References, Referenced in, Features, Featured in and Spoofed in` categories and [this webpage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096874/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) which has  `Follows, Followed by, Edited from, Edited into, Spin-off, References, Referenced in, Features, Featured in, Spoofs and Spoofed in`  categories then the csv output file header will only contain the first webpage's categories i.e `References, Referenced in, Features, Featured in and Spoofed in`  so some categories from the 2nd webpage like `Follows, Followed by, Edited from, Edited into and Spoofs`will not be on the output csv file header so is its contents.
Here is the code i used:

```
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093777/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn',
        'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096874/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {}
        for cnt, h4 in enumerate(response.css('div.list > h4.li_group'), start=1):
            item['Title'] = response.css("h3[itemprop='name'] a::text").extract_first()
            key = h4.xpath('normalize-space()').get().strip()
            if key in ['Follows', 'Followed by', 'Edited into', 'Spun-off from', 'Spin-off', 'Referenced in',
                       'Featured in', 'Spoofed in', 'References', 'Spoofs', 'Version of', 'Remade as', 'Edited from',
                       'Features']:
                values = h4.xpath('following-sibling::div[count(preceding-sibling::h4)=$cnt]', cnt=cnt).xpath(
                    'string(.//a)').getall(),
                item[key] = values
        yield item
```

and here is `exporters.py` file:

```
try:
    from itertools import zip_longest as zip_longest
except:
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy.conf import settings


class NewLineRowCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, include_headers_line=True, join_multivalued=',', **kwargs):
        super(NewLineRowCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(file, include_headers_line, join_multivalued, **kwargs)

    def export_item(self, item):
        if self._headers_not_written:
            self._headers_not_written = False
            self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)

        fields = self._get_serialized_fields(item, default_value='',
                                             include_empty=True)
        values = list(self._build_row(x for _, x in fields))

        values = [
            (val[0] if len(val) == 1 and type(val[0]) in (list, tuple) else val)
            if type(val) in (list, tuple)
            else (val, )
            for val in values]

        multi_row = zip_longest(*values, fillvalue='')

        for row in multi_row:
            self.csv_writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

What I'm trying to achieve is i want all these categories to be on the csv output header.

```
'Follows', 'Followed by', 'Edited into', 'Spun-off from', 'Spin-off', 'Referenced in',
'Featured in', 'Spoofed in', 'References', 'Spoofs', 'Version of', 'Remade as', 'Edited from', 'Features'
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Please ask one question at a time only, else answers and comments get mixed up.

Comment: You would need to add some more code for us to understand where you are going wrong, and to enable us to also recreate your current problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the title using below

```
item = {}
item['Title'] = response.css("h3[itemprop='name'] a::text").extract_first()
```

For the CSV part you would need to create a FeedExports which can split each row into multiple rows

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter


class NewLineRowCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, include_headers_line=True, join_multivalued=',', **kwargs):
        super(NewLineRowCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(file, include_headers_line, join_multivalued, **kwargs)

    def export_item(self, item):
        if self._headers_not_written:
            self._headers_not_written = False
            self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)

        fields = self._get_serialized_fields(item, default_value='',
                                             include_empty=True)
        values = list(self._build_row(x for _, x in fields))

        values = [
            (val[0] if len(val) == 1 and type(val[0]) in (list, tuple) else val)
            if type(val) in (list, tuple)
            else (val, )
            for val in values]

        multi_row = zip_longest(*values, fillvalue='')

        for row in multi_row:
            self.csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Then you need to assign the feed exporter in your settings

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': '<yourproject>.exporters.NewLineRowCsvItemExporter',
}
```

Assuming you put the code in `exporters.py` file. The output will be as desired

[image: Exported Data]

**Edit-1**

To set the fields and their order you will need to define `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` in your `settings.py`

```
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ['Title', 'Follows', 'Followed by', 'Edited into', 'Spun-off from', 'Spin-off', 'Referenced in',
                       'Featured in', 'Spoofed in', 'References', 'Spoofs', 'Version of', 'Remade as', 'Edited from',
                       'Features']
```

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks, works like charm! But The Rows Only Includes   _Title_  _Spoofs_  _Follows_  _Referenced in_ _Featured in_ _References_  _Followed by_ and It's Giving me this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Using python or python3? Try using python3 if you are on Python 2

Comment: @TarunLalwani I updated the question. if you can, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To set csv data format one of the easiest way is to clean data using excel power queries follow these steps:
1: open csv file in excel.
2:select all values using ctrl+A
3:Then click on table from insert and create table.
4:after create table click on Data from top menu and select From Table   5:know they open new excel window power queries.
6:select any column and click on split column
7: from split column select by delimiter,
8: know select delimiter like comma,space etc
9: final step select advanced option in which there are two options split in rows or column
10: you can do all type of data cleaning using these power queries this is the easiest way to setup data format according to your need