# Scrape item with many variations not to list or dict, but each one per row(multiple rows)

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Try to scrape product's info(title, price, variations etc) and output to csv.
 
So title, price and other data with 1 element should hold one cell, but data with many variant should be one variant per row, such way [spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlBlr.png).
In my code column with many variations is color names, color image urls and color variation urls, and I want to each element per new row instead of list format in one cell.
How can do it?
My code:

```
import scrapy
import string

class KapserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kapser2'
    allowed_domains = ['xpressprofil.no']
    start_urls = ['http://www.xpressprofil.no/sortiment/kapser-hodeplagg/']
def parse(self, response):
    items = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "listing")]')
    for item in items:
        first_url = item.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(first_url)
        price = item.xpath('.//span[@class="listing_price "]/text()').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'price': price})

    next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@rel="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url, callback=self.parse)


def parse_item(self, response):
    item = {}
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//h3[@class="margin-top-0"]/text()').extract_first()
    item['price'] = response.meta['price']
    item['category'] = response.css('.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a::text').extract_first()
    item['sub_category'] = response.css('.breadcrumb li:nth-last-child(2) a::text').extract_first()
    item['image'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="thumbnail"]/img/@src').extract_first()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "product-details")]//p/text()').extract_first()
    sale_price = map(string.strip, response.xpath('//th[contains(@class, "text-right")]/text()').extract())
    sale_price_normalize = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in sale_price]
    min_order_amount = map(string.strip, response.xpath('//td[contains(@class, "text-right")]/text()').extract())
    min_order_amount_normalize = [y.encode('utf-8') for y in min_order_amount]
    item['sales'] = dict(zip(sale_price_normalize, min_order_amount_normalize))
    item['color'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "product-details")]//a[@href[contains(., "htm")]]/img/@alt').extract()
    item['gtin_barcode'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="spec"]//td[contains(., "EAN")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
    item['brand'] = ""
    item['mpn'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="spec"]//td[contains(., "Artikkelnummer")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
    item['delivery_time'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="spec"]//td[contains(., "Leveransetid") or contains(., "Leveringstid")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
    #variations = response.xpath('//select[@data-name="Merking"]//option/text()').extract()

    yield item
```

Update: yes, [How can i export scraped data to csv file in the right format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112590/how-can-i-export-scraped-data-to-csv-file-in-the-right-format) has solved and my question is similar, but it's not work for me. I still output data[red, green, black] in one row instead of one row per variant.
As I understand the problem is in iterates throw values in exporters.py but I can't guess where

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy.conf import settings

class NewLineRowCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, include_headers_line=True, join_multivalued=',', **kwargs):
        super(NewLineRowCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(file, include_headers_line, join_multivalued, **kwargs)

    def export_item(self, item):
        if self._headers_not_written:
            self._headers_not_written = False
            self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)

        fields = self._get_serialized_fields(item, default_value='',
                                             include_empty=True)
        values = list(self._build_row(x for _, x in fields))

        values = [
            (val[0] if len(val) == 1 and type(val[0]) in (list, tuple) else val)
            if type(val) in (list, tuple)
            else (val, )
            for val in values]

        multi_row = izip_longest(*values, fillvalue='')

        for row in multi_row:
            self.csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Output data format in csv: Basic bomullscaps med 5 paneler,Kapser &  Hodeplagg,,Kapser,http://www.xpressprofil.no/sortiment/kapser-hodeplagg/kapser/89545340-225584/basic-bomullscaps-med-5-paneler.htm,,"16,22 kr",,"{'1': '17,91', '100': '17,05', '250': '16,55', '1000': '16,22'}","Hvit,Svart ensfarget,Marineblå,Kongeblå,Rød,Kaki,Grå,Eplegrønn,Oransje,Gul",11106604,//prodimg.unpr.io/itemimage/800/products/500/159637103c53ba.jpg,Basic bomullscaps med 5 paneler. Bomull. 155-160 g/m².
I have lists and dictionary here, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Show us the CSV file you are getting with that code, and show us an example how you want it,

Comment: Update post. This question is duplicate, as [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) noted, but in some case not fit to my problem.